# GitLab EE - path already taken

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

I recently deleted a project.  Now when I try and create it again using the same namespace and name GitLab EE gives me the following error:

"Name has already been taken"
"Path has already been taken"

I'm running EE version 8.7.5-ee.

I also searched the /var/opt/gitlab/git-data directory and removed the directories that referenced my old project.

I tried clearing the redis cache using gitlab-rake cache:clear.  I restarted the services and the server several times.

This normally doesn't happen, but at some point I setup repository mirroring against the repo and I also archived it.  I'm trying to reproduce the issue but in the meantime I can't recreate the project.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a case for commercial support.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I'm engaging them on this.  Pretty sure it's a bug, but hoped maybe someone knew a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

```
$ gitlab-rails console

> route = Route.find_by("path LIKE '%projectname%'")
> route.delete
> route.save
```

Comment: If I encounter this again, I'll try this.  For now, the problem has gone away.  Thanks for taking the time to offer the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your access token.
If access token is created at repository level then this issue will arise.

Solution:

1. create access token at root level (i.e. group,subgroup or gitlab)
2. use newly created access token to perform mirror operations or create repository)